# Java webservice: SOAP over FTP

Tags: java, web-services

In many Java specification I found SOAP support/run different protocols like HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, SMTP etc. 
I searched on google but not found any example or implementation. 
So can anyone here help me to understand this using example?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done it, but my assumption is it's just about the payload format, which would be Soap format. Your Webservice client, will consume the payload from an ftp location and do the processing just like http.